# How to read a text file with mixed data_types automatically in Python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, automation

I have several text files of mixed data types in different columns, 
I want to read them so that the program recognizes each column type **automatically** as I do not know which column contains which type.

When I read only numeric data I used the following, but it fails for mixed datatypes.

```
Import numpy as np
Import csv
train = np.array(list(csv.reader(open(self.source_data_file, "rb"), delimiter=','))).astype('float')
```

Comment: You are trying to store them all as float, please show us what you have tried in order to differentiate between data types.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't know the types of the columns? Usually its best to enforce some ordering on your data through pre/post processing

Comment: @Greg
Thanks many for your care,
The reason I don't know the types of the columns that it is a project about artificial neural networks, I don't knot the data that the user will input, sometimes it has mixed categorical and numeric fields.

Comment: @Remuze
Thanks a lot for your care, 
I tried to read the file line by line, Each line, I tried to store each value as float, using Try: Except, If an exception raised, the value is considered string.
This is my trial and I think it is lengthy and time consuming. that's why I asked experts.
Many thanks again.

Comment: It might help to enforce data types on the user and tell them they inputted something incorrectly if you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `numpy.genfromtxt` here : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

You can read files directly by specifying the delimiter and dtype.
Suppose you have a line in a csv that goes like this:

```
10,120.3,xfghfh
```

You can do the following :

```
data = np.genfromtxt('input_file', dtype=None , delimiter=",")
print (data)
```

which will give you this :

```
data = array((10, 120.3, 'xfghfh'), 
       dtype=[('column_name1', '<i4'), ('column_name2', '<f8'), ('column_name3', 'S6')])
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Do you mean that if we specify the dtype=None, then numpy will specify the data type by itself?

Comment: Yes, dtype is the key there. Please go through the link above for more examples of dtype usage.

Comment: Thank you Sharma, I hope I can upvote your answer, but I still has no reputation :-(
Thumbs UP

Comment: You're welcome ElNesr. I have been in your place too.
You could accept my suggestion as an answer (The tick mark below the Downvote button), you will get 2 rep points for doing so. 
Hopefully I'll get some rep points too ;)